# bulk changing wordpress permalinks

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, permalinks

so I have this odd question that may not be possible to answer... Not really sure, but whatever; I'll ask it anyways... I have a permalink structure as follows:

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/gdp-lesson
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/gdp-test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/demand-lesson
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/demand-test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/supply-lesson
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/supply-test

And I have hundreds of pages at the end of the permalink like that. This is on a wordpress installation, so the page titles respectively are:

GDP - Lesson
GDP - Test

Demand - Lesson
Demand - Test

Supply - Lesson
Supply - Test

I'd like to see if it's possible to run some code or a script or something (idk) that will just modify the permalinks for each of these pages to make them look like:

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/lesson
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/lesson
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/lesson
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/test

while keeping the page titles and everything else the same. I'm not sure if this is possible without screwing up a lot of stuff. If anyone could figure this out, I'd be forever grateful!

Comment: Yes. This is very much possible. 7-8 lines of code can do this. Let me know how are you with the php coding? So I can tell you further about how you can do this.

Comment: hey, i have limited experience with php, but i can follow steps pretty easily